# typeahead returns [object Object] after changing the input text second time

Tags: typeahead.js, angular-ui-typeahead

Typeahead - input box displays `[object Object]` after changing the text the second time.
Let say that in the input text I typed 'newuser' typehead will auto fill all the input fields because 'newuser' is the user on list. After it auto fill I use the back space to delete the text and again typing 'newuser' again then the input box display `[object Object]`
I am using angular-ui-bootstrap typehead
Here is part of my html file

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
      <label class="col-sm-5 control-label">{{'USER.USERNAME' | translate}}:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-7">
        <input type="text" name="username" ng-model="user.username" ng-keypress="keyEnterEvent()" ng-change="userNameChange(user.username)" required ng-init="setTimeout($element.focus(), 500)" typeahead="user as user.username for user in users | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control" validation-tooltip>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So you are actually not using typeahead.js as indicated by the tag? Are you using https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ ?

Comment: some javaScript would be nice :p

Comment: yes, I am using angular-ui-bootstrap version 0.13.4. Any suggestion how to fix this issue